# How to remap Caps Lock key to Shift Left key?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I wan't to remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to the <kbd>Shift Left</kbd> key, so that when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> the functionality of <kbd>Shift Left</kbd> is processed. Is there a file in Ubuntu where I can specify this?

I know, under `/etc/default/keyboard` you can specify some keyboard options, but not this one.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L" #this will make Caps Lock to act as Shift_L
```

To get this change for every session, after you have run the ​​previous commands create a file called `.xmodmap` with the new keymaps, using the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

Comment: Can I just write that first command in `.xinitrc` directly?

Answer (score 1):

enter in terminal:
`xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L"`

To use the command after restart or shutdown, you can put it in Startup Applications Preferences. Tested on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @H M: Can you explain, what the code in the `xmodmap` are doing?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Xmodmap/#Caps-Lock-Taste

Comment: it allows to remap the keys

Comment: You should add this to you answer