# How to remap the right Alt key to perform the Alt key function (within programmer dvorak)?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap, remapping, dvorak

I use the programmer Dvorak keyboard and Ubuntu changed the layout between 13.04 and 14.04 (did not use 13.10).  They changed the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be something else, not even sure what it is.  Consequently, I cannot use it for Emacs, changing workspaces, windowed screenshots etc.  Here is the image of what they changed it to:

[image: keyboard layout]

I want to do exactly what [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/371405/385212) post documents but changing the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be the left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  My real question is what do I replace `keycode 66` and `Shift_L` to be in this command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L"
```

I assume <kbd>Shift_L</kbd> would be instead <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> (or maybe even <kbd>Alt_R</kbd> to restore the 13.04 setting).

---

I ran :

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

then opened up the `.xmodmap` file and found the line:

```
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

which I looked like the right <kbd>Alt<kbd>.  Running:</kbd></kbd>

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 92 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```

did not change the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> but it did mess up the left <kbd>Alt</kbd>, though I am not sure about the specifics.  I reset that to its original value `ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift`.

Reading [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LME6Z.png) post I saw mention of remapping `keycode 108` as the Alt key.  Running :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```

did restore the right Alt to behave as an Alt key.

I am still not sure how to get the settings to persist after rebooting.  I tried regenerating the `.xmodmap` file (`xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap`) then created the `~/.xinitrc` with the line:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

When I reboot, the `~/.xinitrc` file was not executed.  By simply running the command

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

the changes were restored.

I also tried adding the command `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` to the startup programs and it does restore the setting when rebooting.

Lastly, I tried editing the [cron](https://askubuntu.com/a/371405/385212) task:

1. Running `crontab -e` to edit my cron
2. Adding the line

   ```
   @reboot /home/stvn66/bin/remap_keys.sh
   ```

   to run the script `remap_keys.sh` containing one line:

   ```
   xmodmap /home/stvn66/bin/.xmodmap
   ```

None of these setting work to restore my custom settings on reboot.