# Make the caps-lock key do the job of holding shift

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

In Windows 10 when I press the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key, I can type numbers and other special characters. Now, in Ubuntu 18.04, I have to keep pressing the shift button to do that.  Since I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04, this was my biggest problem.

Also how can I remap my own custom keyboard layout?  I searched a lot about this, but I can't find any comprehensible updated tutorial to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976797/how-do-i-install-a-keyboard-layout)

Comment: @K7AAY: The main question is reasonably not a duplicate of the question you linked to, is it?

Comment: It answers "Also how can I remap my own custom keyboard layout? I searched a lot about this, but I can't find any comprehensible updated tutorial to do this."  For the future, please submit a separate Ask Ubuntu question for each question you have as per "Your questions should be reasonably scoped" from https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask . Also, use https://askubuntu.com/search to see if your question has been asked before as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remap Caps Lock key to Shift Left key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371394/how-to-remap-caps-lock-key-to-shift-left-key)

Comment: @K7AAY: Fair enough, and agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Answering the first question in your question. For the future, please submit a separate Ask Ubuntu question for each question you have.]*

Install the `gnome-tweaks` package, if you haven't already done so.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then start Tweaks, navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Caps Lock behavior*, and select **Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock (affects all keys)**.

Comment: Sorry for the second question, I am still new to this..

Comment: @Adolin: No problem, it takes some time to get used to Ask Ubuntu. It doesn't work as a forum, but it's a strict question/answer resource.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. it works when session is running but won't work on login screen. Any idea how to make it work everywhere ? regards

Comment: @skonsoft: For that you can set `XKBOPTIONS="caps:shiftlock"` in `/etc/default/keyboard`.