# How to make Caps Lock key act as Super key?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout

Given: all default 20.04.4 LTS; [IBM Modell 300](https://deskthority.net/wiki/IBM_Enhanced_Keyboard) keyboard, which has no `Super` (`Windows`) key.

How can I let `Caps Lock` key behave as `Super` key?

I tried running `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L"` in a terminal window. An individual press of `Caps Lock` does what `Super` did. However, `Caps Lock`+`D` does not do what `Super`+`D` did (show desktop in GDM3)

Comment: Hello. A search of this site show this is a dupe question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/371394/how-to-remap-caps-lock-key-to-shift-left-key

Comment: This page may provide some insight to your issue: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-change-what-keys-on-the-keyboard-do-how-to-create-custom-keyboard-commands-shortcuts/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In "Gnome Tweaks" (not installed by default), click "Additional Layout Options".

[image]

There, you will find the xkb option "Make CapsLock an additional Super" in the section "Caps Lock Behavior".

[image]

While `xmodmap` also could be used, it is (unfortunately) becoming deprecated in modern desktops. It may be unreliable - stop working when you change keyboard layout, resume from sleep state or attach another keyboard.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a "Keyboard Layout Option" in the (GUI) settings:

Caps Lock behaviour => Make Caps Lock an additional Super.

Comment: I wonder if it's different in GDM3 (default of 20.04). I'm unable to find "Keybaord Layout Options" (looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2ROo.png)